# How to integrate $\int \frac{e^{-x}e^{-y}}{\lvert \vec x - \vec y \rvert} dx dy$ for the helium atom?

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

What methods are used to integrate

$$\int \int \frac{e^{-x}e^{-y}}{\lvert \vec x - \vec y \rvert} dx dy$$

which comes up in perturbation theory calculations such as for the [helium atom](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/08%3A_Multielectron_Atoms/8.02%3A_Perturbation_Theory_and_the_Variational_Method_for_Helium#:%7E:text=Perturbation%20Theory%20of%20the%20Helium%20Atom,-We%20use%20perturbation&text=The%20electron%2Delectron%20repulsion%20term,it%20fit%20the%20new%20problem.) (8.2.6). The integration process itself is often left out, skipping to "in the end we get the answer 34.0". Could anyone show/outline the procedure to perform this integration?

Comment: What is the region of integration?

Comment: @marty cohen i believe it is $0$ to $\infty$. Also $x, y$ are radiuses and must be positive.

Comment: Changing the signs of the exponents definitely helps.

Comment: Switch to polar coordinates. It’s not too bad.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you. The original variables were in radiuses $\int \int \frac{e^{-r_1}e^{-r_2}}{\lvert r_1 - r_2 \rvert}$, could you elaborate as how we can further switch into polar from $r_1, r_2$, please?

Comment: Forget the original variables. Use polar coordinates in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin much appreciated if you could post an answer on this. (34.0 as the answer depended on some other constants present in the ref link).

Comment: Actually, having worked it out, I find that the integral does not converge. Is there perhaps a physical reason that we stay at least a certain distance from the line $x=y$? (Must the two electrons be in different orbitals? What is the minimum distance between those orbitals?) That will explain a relatively large, but finite answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes  x=y might be unphysical due to the Pauli exclusion principle... please continue with the assumption as I'm looking forward to even a limited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, pursuant to the discussion in the comments, here's the solution. We will assume, on physical grounds, that $|x-y|\ge\delta>0$ when we get to the end.

Switching to polar coordinates, we have $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $r>0$, $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{|x-y|}dx\,dy &=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}}{r|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|} r\,dr\,d\theta  \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}}{|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|} \,dr\,d\theta \\ &= 2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}}{\cos\theta-\sin\theta} \,dr\,d\theta.
\end{align*}

Doing the inside integral (with $\int_0^\infty e^{-ar}dr = \frac1a$), we end up with
$$2\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac1{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}d\theta = 2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(2\theta)\,d\theta = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sec u\,du.$$
Since $\sec u\to\infty$ as $u\to\pi/2^-$, we suspect that the integral will diverge. If we bound $u$ away from $\pi/2$ (which is bounding $\theta$ away from $\pi/4$, where $x=y$), then we'll have
\begin{multline*}
2\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\sec u\,du = 2\ln(\sec u+\tan u)\Big|_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon} = 2\ln\left(\tfrac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\right)\Big|_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon} \\ = 2\ln\left(\tfrac{1+\cos\epsilon}{\sin\epsilon}\right) \approx 2\ln (2/\epsilon).\end{multline*}

Comment: thank you very much, the methods and ideas are good to see

Comment: You’re welcome. Don’t forget to accept the answer when you are satisfied with it and have no further questions. :)

Comment: while this does answer the question OP posed, I believe OP’s transcription of the physical problem to a math one is incorrect. The integral to be evaluated is $\int_{\Bbb{R}^3\times\Bbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-|x|} e^{-|y|}}{|x-y|}\,dx\,dy$, where $|x|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of $x\in\Bbb{R}^3$. Now, I don’t feel like (even thinking about) evaluating this integral, but this should be nice and finite. (and if I’m not mistaken, with the correct physical constants out front, we should multiply this by $\frac{\pi^2a_0^2}{2^6}$, with $a_0$ being the Bohr radius).

Comment: oops $a_0^5$, not $a_0^2$…

Comment: @peek-a-boo Interesting points. I’ll think about the right version tomorrow. Brute force doesn’t seem appetizing.

Comment: @TedShifrin i summarized the standard derivation below (turns out it takes a 2 hour lecture to derive)...

Comment: Yes, and you’ve totally changed the question in the meantime.

Comment: @TedShifrin the question is back in its original form :)

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcYUNNSSw_4) and [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-WXW5pyaWA) derivation,

$$\int \frac{e^{ar_1}e^{ar_2}}{\lvert \vec r_1 - \vec r_2 \rvert}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty \color{orange}{\int_0^\pi} \color{red}{\int_0^{2\pi}} e^{ar_1}r_1^2 dr_1 \color{orange}{sin\theta_1  d\theta_1} \color{red}{d\phi_1} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi \color{red}{\int_0^{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\lvert \vec {r1} - \vec {r2} \rvert}e^{ar_2}r_2^2\sin\theta_2dr_2d\theta_2 \color{red}{d\phi_2}$$
$$=\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\int_0^\infty e^{ar_1}r_1^2 dr_1  \int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\lvert \vec {r1} - \vec {r2} \rvert}e^{ar_2}r_2^2\sin\theta_2dr_2d\theta_2$$

since

$$\color{red}{\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi = 2\pi}$$
$$\color{orange}{\int_0^\pi \sin\theta_1 d\theta_1 = 2}$$

So

$$=\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\int_0^\infty r_1^2 e^{ar_1} dr_1  (\color{green}{\int_0^{r_1}} \int_0^\pi \color{green}{\frac{1}{\vec {r1} - \vec {r2}}}r_2^2e^{ar_2}\sin\theta_2\color{green}{dr_2}d\theta_2 + \color{green}{\int_{r_1}^\infty} \int_0^\pi \color{green}{\frac{1}{\lvert \vec {r1} - \vec {r2} \rvert}}r_2^2e^{ar_2}\sin\theta_2\color{green}{dr_2}d\theta_2)$$

$$=\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\int_0^\infty r_1^2 e^{ar_1} dr_1  (\int_0^{r_1} \frac{1}{r_1}  \color{green}{\int_0^\pi{\sin\theta_2\sum_{l=0}^\infty (\frac{r_2}{r_1})^nP_l(\cos\theta_2)d\theta_2}}r_2^2e^{ar_2}dr_2 + \int_{r_1}^\infty \frac{1}{r_2} \color{green}{\int_0^\pi\sin\theta_2\sum_{l=0}^\infty (\frac{r_1}{r_2})^nP_l(\cos\theta_2)d\theta_2}r_2^2e^{ar_2}dr_2)$$

where $P_l$ are the Legendre polynomials,

$$=\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}\int_0^\infty r_1^2 e^{ar_1} dr_1  \left(\int_0^{r_1} \frac{1}{r_1}  r_2^2e^{ar_2}dr_2 + \int_{r_1}^\infty \frac{1}{r_2} r_2^2e^{ar_2}dr_2\right)$$

since

$$ \color{green}{\int_0^\pi{\sin\theta_2\sum_{l=0}^\infty (\frac{r_2}{r_1})^nP_l(\cos\theta_2)d\theta_2} = 2}$$
$$ \color{green}{\int_0^\pi\sin\theta_2\sum_{l=0}^\infty (\frac{r_1}{r_2})^nP_l(\cos\theta_2)d\theta_2 = 2}$$

Changing variables as

$$ ar_1 = \bar r_1$$
$$ ar_2 = \bar r_2$$

We obtain

$$=\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\bar r_1^2}{\color{brown}{a^2}} e^{\bar r_1} \frac{1}{\color{brown}{a}}d\bar r_1  \left(\int_0^{r_1} \frac{\color{brown}{a}}{\bar r_1}  \frac{\bar r_2^2}{\color{brown}{a^2}}e^{\bar r_2}\frac{1}{\color{brown}{a}}d\bar r_2 + \int_{r_1}^\infty \frac{\bar r_2}{\color{brown}{a}}e^{\bar r_2}\frac{1}{\color{brown}{a}}d\bar r_2\right)$$

$$=\frac{\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}}{\color{brown}{a^5}}\int_0^\infty  \bar r_1^2 e^{\bar r_1} d\bar r_1  \left({\frac{1}{\bar r_1}\color{purple}{\int_0^{r_1} \bar r_2^2e^{\bar r_2}d\bar r_2}} + \color{blue}{\int_{r_1}^\infty \bar r_2e^{\bar r_2}d\bar r_2}\right)$$

$$=\frac{\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}}{\color{brown}{a^5}}\int_0^\infty  \bar r_1^2 e^{\bar r_1}   \left({\frac{1}{\bar r_1}\color{purple}{(-\bar r_1^2 e^{-\bar r_1} - 2\bar r_1 e^{-\bar r_1} - 2e^{-\bar r_1} + 2)}} + \color{blue}{\bar r_1e^{-\bar r_1} + e^{-\bar r_1}}\right)d\bar r_1$$

$$=\frac{\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}}{\color{brown}{a^5}}\int_0^\infty \left(-\color{red}{\bar r_1^2e^{-2\bar r_1}} - \color{orange}{2 \bar r_1e^{-2\bar r_1}} + \color{green}{2\bar r_1e^{-\bar r_1}} \right)d\bar r_1$$

But

$$ \color{red}{\int_0^\infty\bar r_1^2e^{-2\bar r_1} d\bar r_1= \frac{1}{4}} $$
$$ \color{orange}{\int_0^\infty\bar r_1e^{-2\bar r_1} d\bar r_1= \frac{1}{4}}$$
$$ \color{green}{\int_0^\infty\bar r_1e^{-\bar r_1} d\bar r_1= 1}$$

Therefore

$$=\frac{\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}}{\color{brown}{a^5}}\left(-\frac{1}{4} - 2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + 2(1) \right)$$
$$=\frac{\color{red}{(2\pi)^2}\color{orange}{(2)}\color{green}{(2)}}{\color{brown}{a^5}}\color{purple}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{20\pi^2}{a^5}$$